# Angular. Validar tamaño de formulario en base a la resolucion de pantalla?

Tags: html, typescript, formularios, validación, angular7

Tengo un formulario de un tamaño especifico, pero quiero que si la pantalla tiene una resolución de menos 1024px, el tamaño del formulario se reduzca( que sea responsivo vaya).
Este es el html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="user">
   <mat-label style="font-family: Roboto;"><b>User</b></mat-label>
       <input style="font-family: Roboto; font-size: 20px;" matInput [(ngModel)]="user">
       <mat-icon class="icon2" matSuffix>account_box</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

esta es la "validacion":

```
<script>
 if (screen.width < 1024) {
   document.write("Pequeña")
 } else { }
</script>
```

Comment: Deberías hacerlo en CSS. Es cómo esta pensado para solucionar este tipo de cosas. Tiene las funciones por reglas de dispositivos, [`@media`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Podrías decirme como? aplicado a este ejemplo

Comment: Olvidalo, ya lo hice y funciono :DD muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo consegui, use las reglas de dispositivos de CSS @media, lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
    .mat-form-field {
      width: 100px;
    }
  }
```